# My twitter bots are posting for each other, and I checked the code. It doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, twitter

I made a twitter bot for my personal Twitter account last night, which turned out perfectly. I even deployed it to Heroku and it worked fine. However, today I built one for my business too, and when I deployed it on Heroku, the two bots started tweeting the same thing.
Here's my code for my personal bot:

```js
console.log('bot is starting');

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./businessconfig');

var T = new Twit(config);

//Setting up stream
var stream = T.stream('user');

//Anytime someone follows me
stream.on('follow', followed);

function followed(event) {
  console.log('Follow event initiated');
  var name = event.source.name;
  var screenName = event.source.screen_name;
  tweetIt('@' + screenName + ' , thanks for following! #twitterbot');
}

function tweetIt(txt) {

    var tweet = {
      status: txt
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

    function tweeted(err, data, response){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
        console.log("Your tweet was posted!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a file titled "business bot.js." The "businessconfig file is my Twitter API key stuff. Here's my personal bot code:

```js
console.log('bot is starting');

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./myconfig');

var T = new Twit(config);

//Setting up stream
var stream = T.stream('user');

//Anytime someone follows me
stream.on('follow', followed);

function followed(event) {
  console.log('Follow event initiated');
  var name = event.source.name;
  var screenName = event.source.screen_name;
  tweetIt('@' + screenName + ' , thanks for following! #twitterbot');
}

function tweetIt(txt) {

    var tweet = {
      status: txt
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

    function tweeted(err, data, response){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
        console.log("Your tweet was posted!");
        }
    }
}
```

It is the same code as the business bot, but they are in different folders and have different package.json files. When I run the node processes, they begin to post with each other. Why do they have a relationship? For instance, if someone follows my personal account, the personal account and business account both tweet "@... Thanks for following! #twitterbot." It doesn't make sense since I made them separately and even changed the file names multiple times. I checked the API keys and they are different. Why do they talk together? Thanks.

Comment: `Here's my code for my personal bot:` : has `var config = require('./businessconfig');` ... seems odd to call the personal config `businessconfig` - typo here? or is it a typo wherever you deployed this bot?

Comment: did you "restart" the bot after changing things

Comment: I deleted my second bot and realized that when someone follows me, I tweet at them like I’m supposed to. However, when I follow someone, I tweet, “Thanks @myownusername...” can you suggest any edits to my code? I’m using the npm package “twit”.

Comment: Have you just changed the whole point of the question?

Comment: Sorry. My question was why the boys weren’t working in general, or at least that’s what it’s meant to be. That was a typo that you mentioned, but that’s not important. I want to know why the bot is tweeting at myself when I follow someone.

Comment: I meant bots, not boys

Comment: I deleted the other to isolate the problem and it turns out they aren’t linked. They just both have the same issue of commenting on their own follows.

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite the question rather than make changes to the question in comments